# $S$ is the set of words generated by an alphabet. $A\subset S$ , $x\in S$. How to find if $x$ is generated by concatenating elements of $A$?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algorithms, semigroups

I am looking for references in relation to this problem. The name of the problem, texts or papers, efficient algorithms, and calculators.

Example:

$S$= the set of all finite binary strings, $A$= a finite subset of $S$, $x$= a particular finite binary string. Determine if $x$ can be obtained by concatenating elements of $A$ (repetition allowed).

Of course one can do brute force. Calculate $A^n$ and check, keeping branches that overlap with $x$. Are there more efficient algorithms?

Comment: What if $A$ is already a semigroup and $x \in S \setminus A$?

Comment: @azif00  in many particular cases it is possible to give a negative answer. I am looking for a general approach that gives the construction of $x$ from $A$ if possible.

Comment: I'd call it the "Semigroup membership problem". This is similar to the case of ideals or more generally, submodules, where Groebner bases can be used to classify membership. For semigroups, I'm not so sure, but "Graver bases" comes to mind.

Comment: Your question is very poorly stated. Since you are talking of algorithms, the first thing to clarify is: what is the input of your algorithm. In other words, how is your semigroup given? By generators and relations? As a semigroup of transformations, of matrices, etc. ?

Comment: You totally changed your question, but it was closed two days ago and it is not currently accepting answers.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin  There is a "Reopen" button where you can vote for reactivation if you think the question is ok.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**:

For your example - you can build a non-deterministic FSM in the spirit of Aho-Corasick algorithm (transitions = elements of $A$), and feed $x$ to that FSM to get an answer.

However, this approach does not generalize well to an arbitrary semigroup/monoid/group.